# Getting the minimum qty allowed in a shopping cart without deprecated methods

Tags: magento2, stock, inventory, registry, stock-availability

Previously to get the minimum qty allowed in a shopping cart I would use the following code:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
){
    $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
}

public function getMinSaleQtyAllowed($productId): float
{
    $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($productId);
    return $stockItem->getMinSaleQty();
}
```

However, `Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface` is now deprecated and I can not see how to get the minimum qty allowed without using it.

Please could someone advise?

Answer (score 1):

Well... That's long-winded ha!

```
    public function __construct(
        Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\StockResolverInterface             $stockResolver,
        Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface              $storeManager,
        Magento\InventoryConfigurationApi\Api\GetStockItemConfigurationInterface $getStockItemConfiguration
    )
    {
        $this->stockResolver = $stockResolver;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->getStockItemConfiguration = $getStockItemConfiguration;
    }

    public function getMinSaleQtyAllowed($productSku): float
    {
            $websiteCode = $this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getCode();
            $stock = $this->stockResolver->execute(SalesChannelInterface::TYPE_WEBSITE, $websiteCode);
            $stockId = (int)$stock->getStockId();
    
            $stockItemConfiguration = $this->getStockItemConfiguration->execute($productSku, $stockId);
    
            return $stockItemConfiguration->getMinSaleQty();
    }
```